# Find the next value in the sequence

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

Given the following:

> 1, 10, 18, 40, 46, 52, 61

what is the next value in the sequence?

Hint:

> Think 1-10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is:

> $63$. They're numbers that when you flip the digits, it gives you a perfect square. Take all such numbers and arrange in ascending order.

Comment: They're certainly that, but why that one next in particular? (I've so far failed to spot whatever pattern there may be in the sequence.)

Comment: It's the next number, unflipped, that when flipped gives you a square. The squares aren't in any particular order, I don't think, the unflipped number just has to give you a square when flipped.

Comment: You have the right number, but *why* is an important aspect as well. The order is not random.

Comment: Is it significant that 4 and 9 aren't on the list while 1 is?

Comment: I added a hint to the question that should help you figure out the missing details.

Comment: It looks as if the flipped numbers are in ascending order ... except that I don't understand what determines how many zeros to add at the end of each. (This is pretty much the same thing as DooplissForce's last question.)

Comment: If there is a clear criterion that says which zero-affixed versions of each number are eligible for inclusion, then the ascending-order condition would in fact determine the order we need completely.

Comment: Now that I look at it, the trailing zeros are an issue. I should have just done 1-9 instead of 1-10, and used two digits for each.